# Facebook Page Feed Webhook work in test but not when live

Tags: facebook, webhooks

I have created a webhook to receive feed updates. I want to be notified when a post is liked or commented on or shared. I have set the endpoints up in a script on my server, i have also set up the webhook in the developers console. When i send a test event from the dev console in the webhook section my endpoint receives and processes it fine. When i set my app to live, nothing seems to be sent to the webhook from my page when i like or comment or post. I have followed all the instructions exactly. I have subscribed my page to the app and checked that it is subscribed, and also i have set my app to live. Yet there are still no webhook events received... Any one got any idea what im missing??

Comment: Did you submit your app for review regarding the relevant permission(s)? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks#permissions

Comment: @misorude  There are no permissions needed for this tho? What am i missing?

Comment: Yes there are, you need at least manage_pages to subscribe your page for updates in the first place.

Comment: @misorude But i used graph explorer to generate a token while in development mode to do the subscription. I have checked it and it is definitely subscribed. Also there is nowhere in the docs that says you have to have the manage_pages permission???

Comment: _“Also there is nowhere in the docs that says you have to have the manage_pages permission?”_ - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/reference

Comment: Yes sorry i get what you mean now, i have done that from my profile you can do it in development mode without having to submit your app for review. In dev mode, add the scope to the login flow, login as admin, grant permission... job done.. need to submit for review to do that... so anyway i'm filling out the app review forms now... lets see if that will solve the issue as you say it will. I bet it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

you have to get this permission pages_manage_metadata to get the feed activity on your webhook

Comment: This should be a comment.